# cannot choose knn_vector when creating an index in opensearch

Tags: indexing, mapping, knn, embedding, opensearch

I am having a weird problem when studying opensearch and use it's embedding vectors.

I create an index from opensearch dashboard like this:

[image]

[image]

You can see that vector_field is a float now.

But I created the same one a few days ago. I could choose 'knn_vector' from the drop list. But it is missing this time.

Compared to the index that I created before, I find there is some difference in advanced setting:

[image]

You can see there is two lines about knn here, which is missing from my current index (see first picture). I cannot directly copy and paste.

So how can i choose 'knn_vector'?